# How to include data object files (images, etc.) in program and access the symbols?

Tags: c++, c, assembly, linker, undefined-reference

I've turned a couple of resource files into .obj files using `objcopy` and i link them with my programs source code.
I can very well access the symbols inside the object file in my program with the following code, but only with GCC/G++ (Cygwin):

```
extern uint8_t data[]   asm("_binary_Resources_0_png_start");
extern uint8_t size[]   asm("_binary_Resources_0_png_size");
extern uint8_t end[]    asm("_binary_Resources_0_png_end");
```

The code doesn't work in Visual Studio, probably because VS has it's own `__asm` command.
I want to include my programs resources (Images, Shaders, etc.) in my final executable's `.data` section through linking them.

But how can i access the symbols defined in the object file in VC++?
I tried `extern uint8_t _binary_Resources_0_png_start[]` or `extern "C" uint8_t _binary_Resources_0_png_start[]` without the assembly command, but i get unresolved symbol link errors.

Comment: maybe calling the symbols `_data`, `_size` ... would help. you could get rid of the `asm` part then. I did the same thing, but created asm files from binary instead of using `objcopy`, that gives control on the symbol names.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I tried having the variables in my program have the same name as their corresponding symbol name, but to no avail.

Comment: You tagged this question C and C++. I assumed "C". I modified my answer to assume you really mean C++ since the bottom of your answer suggests that is what you are really using. My answer was amended to add `extern "C"` to each external variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After working around and testing different things, i came back to my original approach (linking) and it worked like magic, here is the details:

In order to include data in the final executable's `.data` section, you need to first turn that data files (which could be an arbitrary binary file (anything!)) into a linkable file format, also known as an object file.

The tool `objcopy` which is included in `GNU Binutils` and is accessible in windows through `Cygwin` or `MinGW`, takes a file and produces an object file. objcopy requires two things to know before generating the object file, the output file format and the output architecture.
In order to determine these two things, i check a valid linkable object file with the tool `objdump`:

```
objdump -f main.o
```

This gives me the following information:

```
main.o:     file format pe-x86-64
architecture: i386:x86-64, flags 0x00000039:
HAS_RELOC, HAS_DEBUG, HAS_SYMS, HAS_LOCALS
start address 0x0000000000000000
```

With this knowledge now i can create the object file:

```
objcopy -I binary -O pe-x86-64 -B i386 data_file.data data_file_data.o
```

In order to handle large number of files, batch files could come in handy.

I then simply link the produced object file(s) together with my programs source and dereference the pointers that objcopy generated, through the symbols, whose names could easily be queried with:

```
objdump -t data_file_data.o
```

Which results in:

```
data_file_data.o:     file format pe-x86-64

SYMBOL TABLE:
[  0](sec  1)(fl 0x00)(ty  0)(scl  2) (nx 0) 0x0000000000000000 _binary_data_file_data_start
[  1](sec  1)(fl 0x00)(ty  0)(scl  2) (nx 0) 0x0000000000000006 _binary_data_file_data_end
[  2](sec -1)(fl 0x00)(ty  0)(scl  2) (nx 0) 0x0000000000000006 _binary_data_file_data_size
```

Practically speaking, the following code works with `GCC/G++`:

```
extern uint8_t data[]   asm("_binary_data_file_data_start");
extern uint8_t end[]    asm("_binary_data_file_data_end");
```

And the following with `MSVC++`:

```
extern "C" uint8_t _binary_data_file_data_start[]; // Same name as symbol
extern "C" uint8_t _binary_data_file_data_end[];   // Same name as symbol
```

The size of each each file is calculated with:

```
_binary_data_file_data_end - _binary_data_file_data_start
```

You could for example write the data back into a file:

```
FILE* file;

file = fopen("data_file_reproduced.data", "wb");
fwrite(_binary_data_file_data_start,                               //Pointer to data
       1,                                                          //Write block size
       _binary_data_file_data_end - _binary_data_file_data_start,  //Data size
       file);

fclose(file);
```

Comment: For read-only data, you should use the example from the man page: `--rename-section .data=.rodata,alloc,load,readonly,data,contents`.  That will put the symbols in `section .rodata`

Comment: Your question originally didn't say this was for 64-bit code or 32-bit code. I have redone my answer to point out the difference between 32-bit and 64 WinPE formats and the little difference in name decorating (namely that pe-x86-64 format doesn't name decorate by adding an additional `_` to global labels). There is still no need for `asm` directive when using G++ either.

Answer (score 5):

The trick with `objcopy` isn't meant as a full-featured way to embed resources and isn't portable at all, as you have seen.

Microsoft has its own mechanism for resources, so if you're specifically targeting windows, you could use a windows resource file and the [RCDATA resource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381039(v=vs.85).aspx).

If you want something completely portable, your only option is to format the file as C sourcecode like e.g.

```
const uint8_t my_binary[] = { 0x00, 0x01, ... }
```

It's straight forward to write your own conversion tool for that.

Comment: @chakmeshma please keep it in english :) It's the only portable way and the size in the resulting binary is the same, so why care? Source sizes can be huge, oh well ...

Comment: And once you have the source-code generator you can generate the C source on the fly anyway, so the big ugly files never need to be added to source control. If they're only local and transient, it really doesn't matter.

Comment: `objcopy` is portable, the way the externs is done in this code (and some tutorials) is non-portable and not the correct way of doing them. The ASM directive isn't needed at all if done properly.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I don't consider objcopy "portable". It creates a plain object file in several supported formats (e.g. **not** including the format my C64 compiler uses *g* -- but probably some others as well) using symbol names that might have to be referenced differently on different platforms. Maybe call it limited portability.

Answer (score 4):

It is a may be completely different approach but it provides a rather simple but portable solution:

We use a small tool to load a binary file and output it as C (or C++ source). Actually, I saw things like this in XPM and GIMP but it can be used for rather any binary data.

To include such tool in the build chain is not difficult in VS, even more simple in `make` and `cmake` also.

Such a tool could look like this:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  if (argc < 2) {
    cerr << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " FILE [FILE...]" << endl;
    return -1;
  }
  for (size_t i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
    fstream fIn(argv[i], ios::in | ios::binary);
    if (!fIn.good()) {
      cerr << "ERROR: Cannot open '" << argv[i] << "'!" << endl;
      continue;
    }
    // make name
    string name = argv[i];
    name = name.substr(0, name.find('.'));
    /// @todo more sophisticated name mangling?
    // print preface
    cout << "struct { const char *data; size_t size; } " << name << " = {" << endl
      << "  \"";
    // print data
    const char hex[] = "0123456789abcdef";
    unsigned char byte;
    enum { BytesPerLine = 16 };
    size_t n = 0;
    for (unsigned char byte; fIn.get((char&)byte); ++n) {
      if (n && !(n % BytesPerLine)) cout << "\"\n  \"";
      cout << "\\x" << hex[byte / 16] << hex[byte % 16];
    }
    // print size
    cout << "\",\n"
      "  " << n << "\n"
      "};" << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Compiling and test:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 -o binToC binToC.cc

$ ./binToC
Usage: ./binToC FILE [FILE...]
```

More testing with `fluffy_cat.png` [image: fluff_cat.png]:

```
$ ./binToC fluffy_cat.png > fluffy_cat.inc

$ cat >fluffy_cat_test.cc <<'EOF'
> #include <fstream>
> 
> using namespace std;
> 
> #include "fluffy_cat.inc"
> 
> int main()
> {
>   ofstream fOut("fluffy_cat_test.png", ios::out | ios::binary);
>   fOut.write(fluffy_cat.data, fluffy_cat.size);
>   fOut.close();
>   return 0;
> }
> EOF

$ g++ -std=c++11 -o fluffy_cat_test fluffy_cat_test.cc

$ ./fluffy_cat_test

$ diff fluffy_cat.png fluffy_cat_test.png

$
```

As the `diff` shows – the C source reproduces the original exactly.

Btw. I used the same technique (in similar form) in my answer to [SO: Paint a rect on qglwidget at specifit times](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42420804/7478597).

Comment: As there is some non-empty intersection in the answer of Felix Palmen and mine, I've invested some additional effort and added a code sample.

Comment: this doesn't work with non-trivial files since MSVC has a 64k character limit on literals.

Answer (score 2):

Your question originally didn't state whether this is for 64-bit Cygwin G++/MSVC++ or 32-bit. There is a subtle difference when it comes to name decorations.

---

### x86 (32-bit Windows PE) solution with OBJCOPY

I'll assume you had a resource file called `Resources_0.png`. You can generate a 32-bit Windows PE object file with:

```
objcopy --prefix-symbol=_ --input-target binary --output-target \
    pe-i386 --binary-architecture i386 Resources_0.png Resources_0.obj
```

The `--prefix-symbol=_` appends an additional underscore (`_`) to each label. Name decorating with an additional `_` is standard for Win32/PE external object. The resulting file would have produced an object with these labels:

```
__binary_Resources_0_png_start
__binary_Resources_0_png_end
__binary_Resources_0_png_size
```

MSVC++ and Cygwin G++ targeting 32-bit executables can reference these labels as:

```
extern "C" uint8_t _binary_Resources_0_png_start[];
extern "C" uint8_t _binary_Resources_0_png_end[];
extern "C" uint8_t _binary_Resources_0_png_size[];
```

---

### x86-64 (64-bit Windows PE) solution with OBJCOPY

You can generate a 64-bit Windows PE object file with:

```
objcopy --input-target binary --output-target pe-x86-64 --binary-architecture i386 \
    Resources_0.png Resources_0.obj
```

This is similar to the 32-bit however we no longer add an additional underscore (`_`) before each label. That is because in 64-bit PE code the names aren't decorated with an additional underscore.

The resulting file would have produced an object with these labels:

```
_binary_Resources_0_png_start
_binary_Resources_0_png_end
_binary_Resources_0_png_size
```

MSVC++ and Cygwin G++ targeting 64-bit Windows PE executables can reference these labels the exact same was as the 32-bit Windows PE version above:

```
extern "C" uint8_t _binary_Resources_0_png_start[];
extern "C" uint8_t _binary_Resources_0_png_end[];
extern "C" uint8_t _binary_Resources_0_png_size[];
```

**Special note**: When compiling with MSVC++ as 64-bit code you may end up with this linking error when using the `size` label:

> absolute symbol '_binary_Resources_0_png_size' used as target of REL32 relocation in section 4

With 64-bit code you can avoid this by computing the size in your C++ code by using the difference between the `start` and `end` labels like this:

```
size_t binary_Resources_0_png_size = _binary_Resources_0_png_end - \
                                     _binary_Resources_0_png_start;
```

---

### Other Observations

Even if using G++/GCC this is bad form:

```
extern uint8_t data[]   asm("_binary_Resources_0_png_start");
extern uint8_t size[]   asm("_binary_Resources_0_png_size");
extern uint8_t end[]    asm("_binary_Resources_0_png_end");
```

There is little need for doing this and it is less portable. See the solutions above that don't use `asm` directive on variables for G++ code.

---

The question is tagged both C and C++ and the question contains code with `extern "C"`. The answer above assumes you are compiling `.cpp` files with G++/MSVC++. If compiling `.c` files with GCC/MSVC then change `extern "C"` to `extern`

---

If you want to generate Windows PE objects with OBJCOPY where the data is placed in the read-only `.rdata` section rather than `.data` section, you can add this option to the OBJCOPY commands above:

```
--rename-section .data=.rdata,CONTENTS,ALLOC,LOAD,READONLY,DATA
```

I discuss this option in this [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42235175/how-do-i-add-contents-of-text-file-as-a-section-in-an-elf-file/42238374#42238374). The difference being that in Windows PE the read-only section is usually called `.rdata` where as with ELF objects it is `.rodata`

Comment: The ABI on Linux ELF doesn't prepend a leading `_`, but it's inconvenient to get `objcopy` to *not* prepend it . 
 `--remove-leading-char` doesn't do anything when copying from `elf64-x86-64` to `elf64-x86-64`, or when creating from a binary.  `--redefine-sym old=new` does work, but you need to explicitly rename all three symbols.

Comment: Another way might be to first create an object file in a format that does normally use leading underscore, then `--remove-leading-char` would remove it when copying to `elf64-x86-64`?
  I can see why people use `asm("_binary_Resources_0_png_start")`, even though that's ugly and not portable outside of GNU C/C++, because it does make your code portable to any platform with GNU tools.

Comment: @PeterCordes : He isn't using Linux ELF, he's using Windows PE and Cygwin tools. Using objcopy puts the `_` on, the Cygwin GCC/LD use PE and implicitly append by default the underscore.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say what I was talking about.  I meant that your recommendation to never use `asm("_binary_Resources_0_png_start")` isn't as easy to follow on ELF platforms, because `objcopy` still prepends the leading `_`.  So the same source isn't portable between Windows and Linux, without the `asm("_blah")` or with a more complicated way to use `objcopy` depending on the ABI.

Comment: @PeterCordes : You can actually create a C macro that checks the GCC you are using and determine if an underscore is requires and then wrap externs with it of this nature if you so choose. It is *not* necessary to use ASM here if you actually try. But given the fact that isn't what was asked I didn't produce code for that as it doesn't answer the question. The reality is that in this case where the user is using Cygwin G++ or MSVC++ Linux what my answer has is correct. I don't recall seeing this being Linux vs Windows interoperability.

Comment: Hmm, yeah that could work, too, I guess.  I was hoping there was some option to `objcopy` that I was missing; I don't think I'd ever used it before trying it just now.

Comment: @PeterCordes : If you are going to work across platforms then the option is simple IMHO. The `objcopy` command has to have parameters appropriate to the target platform (you need to specify the pe-i386 target when using windows anyway), if you want to on Windows builds is simply add `--prefix-symbol=_` to the objcopy command line used to generate the resource file with the extra underscore.

Comment: Ah yes, that works.  `--prefix_symbol=foo` gives me stuff like `foo_P1000006_JPG_end` on a no-underscore platform, and I could use `_foo` on underscore platforms to get the same C name.  (I'd rather not prepend an extra `_` and always have C variable names that start with `_`.)

Comment: For read-only data, the man page has an example: `--rename-section .data=.rodata,alloc,load,readonly,data,contents`.  That will put the symbols in `section .rodata`, and set the section metadata appropriately.

Comment: @PeterCordes : There is already an SO question and answer about that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42235175/how-do-i-add-contents-of-text-file-as-a-section-in-an-elf-file/42238374#42238374 . Should also point out that on Windows/PE that the readonly section is `.rdata` (not `.rodata` and there may be a number of them that start with the `.rdata`.

Comment: A portable way to do this using GNU tools would be to use `ld` to make the object and then objcopy to rename/redefine, etc.

`ld -r -b binary -o $@ $<` and then `objcopy --rename-section .data... $@ $@`
`