# Overpainting 2D graphics over QGLWidget in Python

Tags: python, qt, opengl

```
def paintEvent(self, event):
    """ Paint scene and selected region"""

    super(self.__class__, self).paintGL()
    #Draw selected region

    if self.selectionMode:
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing, True)
        dxx = self.lastPos.x()-self.lastPosInit.x()
        dyy = self.lastPos.y()- self.lastPosInit.y()
        painter.drawRect(self.lastPosInit.x(), self.lastPosInit.y(), self.pose[0]+dxx, self.pose[1]+dyy)

        # Paint vertexes inside selected volume box
        #for vert in self.meshmodel.point_to_draw:
         #   painter.drawEllipse(vert[0] - 5, vert[1] - 5, 10, 10)
        painter.end()
```

where the parent class is painting OpenGL stuff. When I load the configure file everything is fine:

[image]

My issue is after drawing the bounding box, the mesh colours change:

[image: image2]

Can anyone give help me?

Comment: I added glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); at the top and glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); between the OpenGL and QPainter stuff - and yikes, it works!

Comment: instead of comment you must write a solution and mark it as correct

Comment: Thanks Eyllanesc. But unfortunately stackoverflow is not accepting my answers. What should I do ?

Comment: "But unfortunately stackoverflow is not accepting my answers." The [privilege to asking or answering questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-posts) is granted from the 1st point. (AFAIK, you cannot get less once you are a registered user.) The only exception would be if you were temporarily banned but this doesn't seem to be the case. Thus, why SO shouldn't accept your [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) if it accepted your question? (The only thing: you have to wait 48 hours to _accept_ your own answer.)

Comment: May be interesting: a similar Q/A for [tag:qt] in [tag:c++]: [SO: Paint a rect on qglwidget at specifit times](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42417987/7478597)