# When to use paintEvent and paintGL in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I am using [QOpenGLWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglwidget.html) and can't understand where should I put drawing code: inside overriden [paintGL](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglwidget.html#paintGL) or inside overriden [paintEvent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglwidget.html#paintEvent).

Should I call base class versions of these functions?

How these functions are connected? paintGL launches paintEvent or vice-versa? Maybe they launch as a result of non intersecting reasons (i.e. restore window, draw some 3D geometry, change window size)? What are these reasons then?

Finally, how to force rerender of graphics when I change geometry? What method should I call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer: Open GL drawing in `QOpenGLWidget` should happen in `QOpenGLWidget::paintGL()`.

When OpenGL commands shall be called, a pre-condition is that the resp. OpenGL context has been activated before. This is what [`QOpenGLWidget::paintGL()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglwidget.html#paintGL) ensures:

> There is no need to call [`makeCurrent()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglwidget.html#makeCurrent) because this has already been done when this function is called.
>
> Before invoking this function, the context and the framebuffer are bound, and the viewport is set up by a call to glViewport().

Btw. another pre-condition is that the resp. OpenGL context has been created at all.

---

To find out more about this I digged a bit deeper – in [`QOpenGLWidget::paintEvent()`](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/kernel/qopenglwidget.cpp.html#_ZN13QOpenGLWidget10paintEventEP11QPaintEvent) (on woboq.org):

```
void QOpenGLWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e)
{
    Q_UNUSED(e);
    Q_D(QOpenGLWidget);
    if (!d->initialized)
        return;
    if (updatesEnabled())
        d->render();
}
```

1. The paint event does nothing as long as initialization is not yet done. (I didn't dig deeper but I'm sure that initialization involves calling of `QOpenGLWidget::initializeGL()`.)
2. The paint event requests rendering.

Following the code by eyes (stricly speaking: mouse clicks), `d->render()` calls `QOpenGLWidgetPrivate::render()` which in turn calls finally `QOpenGLWidgetPrivate::invokeUserPaint()` and here we are:

```
void QOpenGLWidgetPrivate::invokeUserPaint()
{
    Q_Q(QOpenGLWidget);
    QOpenGLContext *ctx = QOpenGLContext::currentContext();
    Q_ASSERT(ctx && fbo);
    QOpenGLFunctions *f = ctx->functions();
    QOpenGLContextPrivate::get(ctx)->defaultFboRedirect = fbo->handle();
    f->glViewport(0, 0, q->width() * q->devicePixelRatioF(), q->height() * q->devicePixelRatioF());
    inPaintGL = true;
 // vvvvvvvvvvvv
    q->paintGL();
 // ^^^^^^^^^^^^
    inPaintGL = false;
    flushPending = true;
    QOpenGLContextPrivate::get(ctx)->defaultFboRedirect = 0;
}
```

(The comments are mine.)

So, if `QOpenGLWidget::paintEvent()` is overloaded then it should call the `paintEvent()` of base class. (Otherwise, the OpenGL rendering will certainly break.)

---

> Finally, how to force rerender of graphics when I change geometry? What method should I call?

This is actually answered in the description on `QOpenGLWidget`:

> If you need to trigger a repaint from places other than paintGL() (a typical example is when using timers to animate scenes), you should call the widget's [`update()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#update) function to schedule an update.

---

In case, I misunderstood the intention of OP, and the actual question was where to put `QPainter` drawing in `QOpenGLWidget` – I once wrote an answer to [SO: Paint a rect on qglwidget at specifit times](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42420804/7478597) regarding mixing OpenGL commands and `QPainter` drawing in `paintGL()`.

Comment: Great answer! Now it is clear that when I want to redraw my geometry I can simply call update(), it will call paintEvent(), which finally will call paintGL().

Comment: Yepp, exactly. I was just about to add this part. And it does also mean that window resizing, overlapping, etc. should force updates as well (as usual).